# Browser cache of javascript using stale from disk for 12 hours

Tags: javascript, caching, browser

Recently ran into an issue on an application I develop where the javascript for the application was updated but some customers did not see that change even 12 hours later. We currently send

```
Cache-Control: max-age=3600;
```

alongside our responses to fetch our resource files (such as JS, CSS, HTML snippets, etc.). In this particular case, the javascript was twice in relatively quick succession (henceforth v1, v2). Any users who accessed the pages when v1 was the latest version did not have their caches properly revalidate after v2 was deployed, even after the 3600 seconds of cache max-age have passed. We eventually put v1 back up (~14 hrs later), but the users never actually properly got v2. We do use ETags for our not modified validation on the server side, so there shouldn't be any issues with the JS files having the same filename between v1 and v2.

I realized that we should have been sending

```
must-revalidate
```

alongside the other cache-control above. However, I'm trying to understand what would have caused browsers for the various users to not go and try to revalidate even after the initial cache max-age had expired. Is there a better explanation somewhere about what cases a browser will use a stale resource if there is no must-revalidate specified?

Comment: The correct syntax is `max-age=3600`, FWIW. (If that wasn’t just a typo in the question, maybe browsers default to something longer? I don’t know.) And you shouldn’t send `must-revalidate` to address this; put the hash of the file in its name instead (à la https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev) and make cache never expire.

Comment: That was definitely a typo - fixed. The main issue with adding a hash to the end of the file name or changing the name in any other way is that I use a zero downtime deployment with multiple hosts behind a load balancer, meaning that there's a potential that a user can hit an updated host (JS resources are bundled alongside the application) and not find the required resource files.

Comment: That's a problem in both models; the missing file just makes the problem more obvious. Is it not possible to deploy static files ahead of time to a server/CDN dedicated to static files? That way, you know the old versions still exist – plus it’s more efficient.